# "What reasons do questions get closed for here?" should be in the help center under the "Asking" heading

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons, help-center

Our new off-topic close reasons have come in so handy and been so well used I think they do a good job of giving clear guidance to many on what they can expect they should avoid. Granted they're a subset, but they were chosen due to being such an extremely common subset.

Given that, I think we should add a piece to the help center under the "Asking" heading that lists out all of those fixed off-topic close reasons we have custom for our site, and a detail in the page listing them specifying these are not all the reasons your question may get closed, but these are some of the most common ones.

To be clear, I am asking for a link under the "Asking" heading, to a new page which lists the off-topic close reasons with or without any added explanation for each one that may be useful.

This could also go on the "What types of questions should I avoid asking" page we already have possible. Or have it on another page named something more clear like "What are the most common reasons questions are closed?"

I just think the actual text of those close reasons should be publicized somewhere as they were chosen by the community and have so far been found very effective in meeting much of our close reason needs, and as such may be helpful guidance for others to avoid closure ahead of time rather than finding that text only after having their question closed.

Comment: FYI: We (mods) can't add a new article in the help center, and we can only edit a couple of them (What topics can I ask about here? &  What types of questions should I avoid asking?). So, for this to go through, SE has to get involved.

Comment: @YannisRizos that's one route, alternatively you could edit it into the "What types of questions should I avoid asking?" - Here, let me make it a community led poll.

Comment: @YannisRizos now the community can decide if they even want to bother trying to get this through SE to begin with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Great idea! Except for most of what you said!

### This should go on the "What types of questions should I avoid asking?" page, I don't want a new page added to the help center

Comment: Note moderators can edit the mentioned page, only SE can create a new page in our Help Center.

Answer (score -1):

Great idea! Except for most of what you said!

### This should be a new page and not on the "What types of questions should I avoid asking?" page, I don't want to clutter up that page, or think this content shouldn't have that page's title

Comment: Note only SE can create a new page in our Help Center, so red tape will need to be climbed.

Answer (score -2):

Great idea! Except for most of what you said!

### This should go nowhere! Where should this go? [Nowhere](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6098/what-reasons-do-questions-get-closed-for-here-should-be-in-the-help-center-un/6101#6101).

Comment: If we're going to do this one, it needs to be a recursive link back into itself.